# T-SQL: conditionally setting a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the correct syntax to set a T-SQL variable conditionally, from within a `select` statement?

I have code like the following:

```
select @CreationDate = dm.TS_UP
     , @RegenerateDocument = dm.REGENERATEBLOB
     , @CalculateRelativeToDate = case
                                    when dm.REGENERATEBLOB is null then getdate()
                                    when dm.REGENERATEBLOB = 'Y' then getdate()
                                    when dm.REGENERATEBLOB = 'N' then coalesce(@ApprovalDate, getdate())
                                  end
  from doc_mgmt dm
 where dm.ID_DOC = '11123'
   and dm.ID_PRMRY_TYPE = @CID
   and dm.ID_WRK_TYPE = @IID
```

Notice that none of the branches in the case end on a `null`.

But I am having some trouble with the `@CalculateRelativeToDate` variable, which *sometimes* comes in as `null`. I don't understand why that would be.  In fact, in the case I am testing, the `@RegenerateDocument` flag is set to `Y`, so I think I SHOULD be getting `getdate()`.  But I get `null`.

**What is the correct syntax to set a T-SQL variable conditionally, from within a `select` statement?**

Comment: Your syntax is correct. If it ends up as null, then either none of the `case` branches were taken, or there was no rows in the resultset to calculate against.

Comment: @GSerg: well, the `@RegenerateDocument` variable is getting set to `Y` after I run my select, so I'm not sure how I could not have a row to calculate against.  Hold on a minute while I edit some.

Comment: Are you sure `@RegenerateDocument` didn't already have `Y` prior to the query?

Comment: @GSerg: it did... I'm going to have to rethink how I implement this logic.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the values are set, you can use aggregation.  An aggregation query with no `group by` always returns exactly one row:

```
select @CreationDate = max(dm.TS_UP),
       @RegenerateDocument = max(dm.REGENERATEBLOB),
       @CalculateRelativeToDate = (case when max(dm.REGENERATEBLOB) is null then getdate()
                                        when max(dm.REGENERATEBLOB) = 'Y' then getdate()
                                        when max(dm.REGENERATEBLOB) = 'N' then coalesce(@ApprovalDate, getdate())
                                   end)
from doc_mgmt dm
where dm.ID_DOC = '11123' and
      dm.ID_PRMRY_TYPE = @CID and
      dm.ID_WRK_TYPE = @IID;
```

If you generally expect one row, there is no issue.  The `max()` will return the value from that row.  If no rows match, then the `max()` values will be `NULL` -- which seems to be what you expect.

Comment: Yep, I'm expecting 0 or 1 rows.

Comment: @nomen The query could also be shortened to `... @CalculateRelativeToDate = CASE WHEN max(dm.REGENERATEBLOB) = 'N' THEN coalesce(@ApprovalDate, getdate()) ELSE getDate() END ...`.

Comment: And https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=576f38f5a5815cd7176004a7fdc1e1ca

Comment: And "technically" if you are using at least SQL Server 2012 (which you should be), then you can also do `...CalculateRelativeToDate = 
           IIF( max(dm.REGENERATEBLOB) = 'N', coalesce(@ApprovalDate, getdate()) , getDate() )...`.